How to implement the setting mac address for VF in qdma devise using testpmd application
Hi I am using openNIC design along with qdma drivers for this port representor testing.

click here to get github link for the above
In port representor test I was trying to change the mac address of the PFs and VFs.
for PF I was able to create a function which is given below

int qdma_set_mac_address(struct rte_eth_dev *dev, struct rte_ether_addr *addr)
{
        int i ;
        uint64_t mac_addr = (uint64_t)(uintptr_t)&addr;
        if (!rte_is_valid_assigned_ether_addr(addr))
               return -EADDRNOTAVAIL;
        for (i = 0; i < RTE_ETHER_ADDR_LEN; i++)
                dev->data->mac_addrs[0].addr_bytes[RTE_ETHER_ADDR_LEN -1 -i] =
                                                (uint8_t)((mac_addr >> (BITS_IN_BYTE * i)) & 0xFF);
        return 0;
}


file : drivers/net/qdma/qdma_devops.c
By default if we use testpmd> set vf mac addr <port id> <vf id> <XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX> The below funciton is called.

static void cmd_set_vf_mac_addr_parsed(
        void *parsed_result,
        __rte_unused struct cmdline *cl,
        __rte_unused void *data)
{
        struct cmd_set_vf_mac_addr_result *res = parsed_result;
        int ret = -ENOTSUP;

        if (port_id_is_invalid(res->port_id, ENABLED_WARN))
                return;

#ifdef RTE_NET_IXGBE
        if (ret == -ENOTSUP)
                ret = rte_pmd_ixgbe_set_vf_mac_addr(res->port_id, res->vf_id,
                                &res->mac_addr);
#endif
#ifdef RTE_NET_I40E
        if (ret == -ENOTSUP)
                ret = rte_pmd_i40e_set_vf_mac_addr(res->port_id, res->vf_id,
                                &res->mac_addr);
#endif
#ifdef RTE_NET_BNXT
        if (ret == -ENOTSUP)
                ret = rte_pmd_bnxt_set_vf_mac_addr(res->port_id, res->vf_id,
                                &res->mac_addr);
#endif
     
        switch (ret) {
        case 0:
                break;
        case -EINVAL:
                printf("invalid vf_id %d or mac_addr\n", res->vf_id);
                break;
        case -ENODEV:
                printf("invalid port_id %d\n", res->port_id);
                break;
        case -ENOTSUP:
                printf("function not implemented\n");
                break;
        default:
                printf("programming error: (%s)\n", strerror(-ret));
        }
}

Which is supported only when the pf and vf is ixgbe, i40e or bnxt device. What I am using is the qdma device (i.e: device name of the VF is "qdma_vf").
In qdma driver I can only fetch the function id of the VF.
Can anyone tell how to access the mac address and received packets of the VF using the qdma or is there any other way to access those in qdma device.
Thank you in advance
I need to write a function to change the mac address and read the recived packets of the VF from the PF which in the qdma device using the dpdk testpmd command.
